# How do we make the header(s) shown always at the top of the sheet

Tags: excel

Filter data option in excel is useful to filter data based on a certain criteria. How do we make the header(s) shown at the top always as we scroll down the excel sheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Freeze the row and column

Instructions at : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP001217048.aspx

Comment: This Excel 2010 feature might make freeze panes unnecessary in this situation - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/excel/archive/2010/01/25/table-improvements-in-excel-2010.aspx

Comment: @barrowc unfortunately your link seems to have migrated

Comment: New link for the Excel 2010 features: https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2010/01/25/table-improvements-in-excel-2010

Answer (score 2):

```
View tab
Freeze Panes
- Freeze Panes /* everything to left and above current cell */
- Freeze Top Row
- Freeze First Column
```